# Recover photos from the iTunes backup of a dead iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, photos

My wife's iPhone 4 just died: it won't turn on and doesn't charge. It's basically a brick right now. She needs to recover the photos on it. Is there any way to recover this from the iTunes backup files?

Comment: back up as iCloud back up?

Comment: Nope, just when connecting the phone to the mac.

Comment: Actually I'm not 100% sure she was using iCloud...

Comment: easy, just ask her for log in information in to iCloud.

Comment: Just checked the iCloud account (we use the same). No photos there, just pages, numbers, and stuff like that.

Comment: bad luck, then the Photos sharing was not set up for iCloud. I do not know what "passed away" means but plugging it in to your Mac and using iTunes might do something or not.

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: we shall call it RIP then :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the backup is on a Mac then the free/donationware [iPhone/iPod Touch Backup Extractor](http://supercrazyawesome.com) can help you with this.

1. Download and extract the application.
2. Click "Read Backups" and it should give you a list of available device backups with time stamps of the last time they were backed up.
3. Select your wife's backup and click "Choose".
4. Select "iOS Files" and click "Extract".
5. You'll be prompted for a place to save the extracted files. Select one and click "Extract here".
6. Once the extract is complete a Finder window should pop up. Open the folders Media, then DCIM and you should find your wife's photos in one or more folders called things like 100APPLE.

Comment: Sadly extraction of "iOS Files" outputs nothing for backups made with iOS 10.3.2

Answer (score 3):

If you have backed up to your computer previously, you can use iExplorer to do that sort of thing.

http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/